# Key for Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, key

I am new to API managaments.
I want to use Google Maps API, Directions API, Distance matrix API, Geocoding API, AutoCompleteText API all these stuff in my project.

Will i have to create the "KEY" for every individual APIs or single Maps API key is enough to access all.

Conecting from android.

Please help me.

Comment: check out this : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You need 1 key for google map Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey) (to run google map)

[And 1 key for google place API](https://code.google.com/apis/console) (to run Direction, Distance, Geocoding etc..)

Comment: Thanks Fido. I am going to use only Directions, Distance Matrix, Geocoding, AutoCompletetext . So i need to get Google Place API key alone and not for Maps API. Am i right?

Comment: @user1665651 that's right. The key for google map Android API is only for showing the map

Answer (score 1):

One Api key is enough for all these operations Please visit [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Answer (score 0):

see this here how to set up google key in your app

http://www.remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a35/Android-How-To-Set-Up-an-API-Key-for-Google-Maps.html

And see here also

http://sanathnandasiri.blogspot.in/2011/04/obtaining-google-maps-api-key-for.html